# ADO.NET: do you have lots of stored procedure in your own systems?

Tags: stored-procedures, ado.net, sqlcommand

hi all
We do know that CommandType property of a SqlCommand object has 3 options: TableDirect, Text and StoredProcedure or "SP".

Knowing that "SP" has benefits over two other options, my question is do you make lots of SP in your own systems?

Or What solution do you have instead of creating SP?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside of creating Stored Procedures you can use Object Relational Mapping

Such as:

```
linq to sql
Nhibernate
Entity Framework
```

[Data Access :SP's vs ORMs](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/2009/06/data-access-stored-procedures-vs-orm-ad.html)

Choose the best way that suits you.

Answer (score 1):

In all production system I used SPs and pure ADO.NET Core to access the data. Systems range from having 100-300 tables and about 500-1000 stored procedures.

Most of the Data Access code is generated using a tool. I've posted the source code and sample application on my blog if you're interested in using/modifying it. The tool can generate over 100,000 lines of code in about 20-25 seconds going against a database with about 750 stored procedures.

[Data Access Layer - Code Gen](http://www.matlus.com/data-access-layer-codegen/)

Of course if you're no familiar with Databases, data modeling/design and stored procedures you're probably better off using Linq to SQL or EF4 (Entity Framework version 4) or similar. If you need brute force performance then ADO.NET core along with Stored procedures is the way to go.

Comment: In this case, for every simple task like getting description of a Code, we need to write a "SP".   Is this really a good solution in your point of view?

Comment: That depends on a few factors: 1) The design of your system. 2) The performance requirements of your system (# of transactions per second you have to be able to handle) 3) If for and your team writing stored procedures is just like writing any code and you have tools in place that generate the C# side of your code just because you've written a stored procedure (so you're not really writing the data access code, but just the code in your business layer that calls a method in your data access layer that calls the SP).

Comment: Yes I do think this is a good solution (I wouldn't be doing it if I didn't :)).

Answer (score 1):

**Re: your first question**
When you go down the path of stored procedures, the number of stored procedures begins to grow continually for the life of the project. Outside of the basic CRUD operations, each stored procedure tends to be tightly bound to a particular problem and not very re-usable.  A rule of thumb is that I can expect 8-12 stored procedures for each data table (excluding reference or code tables, such as the list of states or countries).

The very large number of procs makes naming conventions very important so that you can find anything without constantly visually re-scanning the whole list of 400-500 procs.

**Re: your second question**
There are a lot of ugly things that happen with sql written inside of strings inside of C# or VB.NET -- it's error prone, ugly, etc.

Linq, nHybernate and many others exist, but the "concept count" (the number of things you need to learn to start being productive), is much higher than learning how to write a good stored procedure executer in C#.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, as you said, naming conventions seem very important when number of SP increase little by little.  How do you name your own SP?

Comment: the most valuable thing to do is to simulate a namespace, e.g. everything related to human resources is "hr_some_proc", or "hr.some_proc" if you use sql 2005+ schemas. It is not at all useful to prefix things with "usp_" e.g. "user stored procedure", as it is never in question that a sproc is a sproc. Remember, this is like namespaces, not like hungarian notation.

Answer (score 0):

I try to make sure that stored procedures are only created for database functionality - not business logic.

It's **Database Functionality** when I have some database architecture that's a bit obscure and I want to hide that from callers.

It's **Business Logic** when it is simply the *way* in which my application adds or updates or how much validation they do, etc., etc.